# Copying a first child next sibling tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have implemented a class for "first child next sibling" tree in java.

Here is a link representing such a tree

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~novak/cs315116.html

I have implemented the following functions:

```
addChild();
getLabel(); 
setLabel(T v);
getParent();
getNextSibling();
getFirstChild();
```

My addChild functions adds the children in the following order.

```
public void addChild(Tree<T> c) {
     c.parent = this;
     if (firstChild == null) 
       firstChild = c;
     else {
         c.nextSibling = firstChild;
         firstChild = c;
        }
}

That is, if we have a tree node 1 and we add tree node 2 and then tree node 3 to it then the final tree would be,
1.addChild(2);
1.addChild(3);

 1                                          1
/ \    which is internally stored as       /
3   2                                      3 - 2
The most recent child added would be the first child
```

I want to implement a CopyTree function which, when given any such tree as an argument will create a copy of the tree and return it.
I have some initial code but I am unable to get the correct recursion.

```
private Tree<String> CopyTree(Tree<String> tr){
if (tr == null)
    return null;
Tree<String> t = new Tree<String>();
t.setLabel(tr.getLabel());
if (tr.getFirstChild() != null) {
    t.addChild(CopyTree(tr.getFirstChild()));
}
Tree<String> temp = tr.left();

if (temp != null) {
while (temp.getNextSibling() != null) {
    t.addChild(CopyTree(temp.getNextSibling()));
    temp = temp.getNextSibling();
}
}
return t;
}
```

What to do in order to make the recursion work??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it..

```
private Tree<String> CopyTree(Tree<String> tr){
if (tr == null)
    return null;
Tree<String> t = new Tree<String>();
t.setLabel(tr.getLabel());

Tree<String> temp = tr.left();

if (temp != null) {
    ArrayList<Tree<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (temp.getNextSibling() != null) {
    list.add(temp.getNextSibling());
    //t.addChild(CopyTree(temp.getNextSibling()));
    temp = temp.getNextSibling();
}
for (int i = (list.size()-1); i>=0; i--) {
    t.addChild(CopyTree(list.get(i)));
}

}
if (tr.left() != null) {
    t.addChild(CopyTree(tr.left()));
}

return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe you have an error here:

```
 while (temp.getNextSibling() != null) {
    t.addChild(CopyTree(temp.getNextSibling()));
    temp = temp.getNextSibling();
}
```

Since getNextSibling() retuns the next children to the right, but addChild() inserts a children from the left, you are reversing the order here. This might be ok, but try to avoid this.

To answer your question, your recursion function should be called as a method on each node of the new Tree and receive the corresponding node of the old tree as an argument. It should then copy the children of this node from the old tree in the new one and, while doing this, call the recursion function on each of these children.